# SQL Server - frequent database backups

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a service that synchronizes data between two databases. This is quite risky mostly because this is new software that is not very well tested. This is why I need to do frequent backups - before every sync(the service performs that itself). After one day I got 13.9 gb file with backups. This is TOO MUCH.

I'm considering what are my options here and what to do with this. I'm trying to divide this database into two filegroups - primary and photos. After doing this I got 16mb and 120mb files. The important thing here is to backup those 16mb and be able to restore it when needed.

I don't really know what risks are here and what can happen. Can anyone briefly explain or give a link so that I can read?

What other options are there?

(The ultimate goal is that I can backup frequently with relatively small backup file sizes )

Comment: With regards the "synchronization" are you sync'ing to another sql server instance? Any reason why you why you didn't go with a tried and tested technology like SQL Server Replication?

Comment: I'm synchronizing data between two completely different databases one from accounting software and the other e-commerce asp.net website. Both of them are using SQL Server.

Answer (score 2):

You have tagged this question with MSSQL 2008.

MS SQL 2008 can utilize `FILESTREAM` to store collections of files in the filesystem rather than as blobs in the DB. However, it retains the ability to track and index the file locations.

In that case, when your sync service executes it should also transfer the contents of the `FILESTREAM` directory.

The result will be that your DB backups will be significantly smaller because they don't actually contain the files, just the locations and tables required for data integrity.

Here is an informative link on the `FILESTREAM` feature: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc949109(v=sql.100).aspx

Comment: This is great option! I'll try to implement it.

Comment: Um, Backups include the filestream data. Read the Integrated Management section from http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933993.aspx (or, in fact, search the link you included for the word Backup)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever sure it does but because the file data is kept separate from the row, a simple update on the row does not cause the file to be copied again on an incremental plan.

Answer (score 0):

> I have a service that synchronizes
>   data between two databases. This is
>   quite risky mostly because this is new
>   software that is not very well tested.
>   This is why I need to do frequent
>   backups - before every sync(the
>   service performs that itself). After
>   one day I got 13.9 gb file with
>   backups. This is TOO MUCH.

Please donot forget to shrink the log file before taking the database backup to avoid the unnecessary usage of Disk.

```
USE DatabaseName
GO
DBCC SHRINKFILE(LogFileName, 1)
BACKUP LOG DatabaseName WITH TRUNCATE_ONLY
DBCC SHRINKFILE(LogFile, 1)
GO
```

Comment: I've already done that. Shrinking doesn't really help - the log file was 267mb in size when I last checked and 0.25 mb free space was allocated. Thanks for reminding:)